# "Green-Chemistry" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Should there be different [green-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-chemistry) tag or it should be included in [environmental-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-chemistry)

Comment: Environmental chemistry is chemistry that relates to the environment.  Green chemistry is different as it would relate to sustainability, promotion of a green environment, etc., something the latter doesn't necessarily do.  I think there is clearly a difference and both tags should exist.

Comment: I do agree with @LordStryker. Could you add some questions, where this tag would be appropriate (or start retagging). If there are no questions, that need the tag, it simply just does not exist.

Comment: @Martin We now have a couple of questions tagged with green-chemistry.

Comment: @Martin [Here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/efforts-made-to-reduce-the-amount-of-cfc?noredirect=1#comment29048_18997) is green-chemistry question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environmental chemistry is chemistry that relates to the environment. Green chemistry is different as it would relate to sustainability, promotion of a green environment, etc., something the latter doesn't necessarily do. I think there is clearly a difference and both tags should exist.

We now have a couple of questions tagged with [green-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-chemistry).

[Efforts made to reduce the amount of CFC](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/18997/efforts-made-to-reduce-the-amount-of-cfc?noredirect=1#comment29048_18997)

[How does the work that won the 2012 Sustainable Chemistry Award contribute to sustainable chemistry?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/1280/how-does-the-work-that-won-the-2012-sustainable-chemistry-award-contribute-to-su)